# How to display join query results on a sublayer in CartoDB.js application?

Tags: postgresql, javascript, carto

I'm working with my first CartoDB.js application.

I created a visualization on the app using

```
cartodb.createVis('map', visjson_url, opts);
```

The app has two layers, base map and data layer.
the data layer has five sublayers. Each sublayer represents data in an independent table (i.e., sublayer1 represents table1, etc.).

I run queries using this statement:

```
data_layer.getSubLayer(sublayer_index).setSQL(query_str);
```

The problem is that I get an error message saying "Bad Request" if query_str involves join operations between some of the tables (e.g., spatial join between table1 and table3). If query_str is related to only one table (without joins), `setSQL()` above works fine.

How can I display join results using `setSQL()` that involves join operation between two or more sublayers?

Comment: Have you tried the same queries through the SQL tray in your CartoDB account? Could you share a sample query here? `layer.setSQL(...)` supports arbitrary queries against your database.

Comment: Andy, thank you for your attention. I ran `$.getJSON('https://myaccount.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql/?q=SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN field1 ON ST_Intersects(table1.the_geom, table2.the_geom) INNER JOIN table3 ON ST_Intersects(table2.the_geom, table3.the_geom)', function(data) { console.log(data); });` on the javascript console of the webbrowser. It doesn't give me the error. This is why I thought there's an error in visualizing part, rather than DB access. Any advice will be appreciated.